# In VB.net, does a subclass that shadows a method in the super class still comply with the interface the super class complies with?

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Ok, so I have a scenario kind of like this. First of all, I have an interface, I'll call it Iinterface, and in the interface there is a method (i'll call it method).
Now I have a superclass, that implements the interface and a method that implements the method in the interface. There is a subclass that inherits from the superclass, however in the subclass, the method in the superclass that originally implemented the method has been shadowed by a different method with the same name and signiture.

In this case, would the subclass still implement the interface?

Specifically, would this work?

```
Dim stuff as Iinterface
stuff = new SuperClass
'do some things
stuff = new SubClass
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind a compiler warning, you *can* have a `Shadows` method that does implement the interface (again) explicitly.

```
Class MySubClass3
    Inherits MySuperClass
    Implements IMyInterface
    Public Shadows Sub MyMethod(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As String) Implements IMyInterface.MyMethod
        MsgBox("Shadowed re-Implemented MyMethod")
    End Sub
End Class
```

And even though the warning is provided, this is still a `Shadows` method as compiled (so

```
    Dim mysTest As MySuperClass = New MySubClass3
    mysTest.MyMethod(1, "a")
```

still displays "Original MyMethod"). As the [Microsoft description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwwt4s94.aspx) for this warning explains, as you *do* intend reimplementation of the method, the warning must be ignored or explicitly disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the original SuperClass method would still implement the interface, but using the original Superclass method. If the signature is the same, then use Overrides instead of Shadows. If it doesn't have the same signature, you are unable to implement the interface anyway.

```
Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim myiTest As IMyInterface
    myiTest = New MySuperClass
    myiTest.MyMethod(1, "a")
    myiTest = New MySubClass
    myiTest.MyMethod(1, "a")
    myiTest = New MySubClass2
    myiTest.MyMethod(1, "a")
  End Sub


  Interface IMyInterface
    Sub MyMethod(a As Integer, b As String)
  End Interface

  Class MySuperClass
    Implements IMyInterface

    Public Overridable Sub MyMethod(a As Integer, b As String) Implements IMyInterface.MyMethod
      MsgBox("Original MyMethod")
    End Sub
  End Class

  Class MySubClass
    Inherits MySuperClass
    Public Shadows Sub MyMethod(a As Integer, b As String)
      MsgBox("Shadowed MyMethod")
    End Sub
  End Class

  Class MySubClass2
    Inherits MySuperClass
    Public Overrides Sub MyMethod(a As Integer, b As String)
       MsgBox("Overridden MyMethod")
    End Sub
  End Class
End Module
```